# How can I insert multiple objects into an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query where I'm trying to push multiple objects into an array. Here is the code I have:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    created : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now
    },
    modified : Date,
    phone: [{
        kind: String,
        number: String
    }],
    pic : String,
});

var phones = [
    {"kind":"Cell","number":"343-343-3434"},
    {"kind":"Work","number":"454-454-4545"}
];

User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.user_id,
    {"$push": {"phone": {"$each": phones}}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
         }
    }
);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR = MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $push
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which mongoose and MongoDB server version?

Comment: I'm using modulus.io. I couldn't find out what version of mongodb they are using.

Comment: Presumably you can connect with a mongo shell? Use `db.serverStatus().version` in the shell to get the server version. The version of mongoose can be found by `npm list` in your project directory.

Comment: I'm using mongodb version 3.4.1. Mongoose version 3.8.22.

Comment: I found that it works when using ``update`` instead of ``findByIdAndUpdate``.